# Are my lines instanced?

Tags: c++, directx, graphics-programming, directx10

I have a class which "collects" line mesh transformations throughout the update and then draws them in one place by drawing one line over and over again. I'll post the code below. I'm just wondering if this is instanced or if the idea is to join them all into one mega-mesh and send that through?

Or if I'm missing some key-part altogether....

```
void BatchLineRenderer::RenderLines(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection)
{
    device->IASetInputLayout(pVertexLayout);

    device->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINESTRIP);

    // select which vertex buffer and index buffer to display
    UINT stride = sizeof(LINE);
    UINT offset = 0;
    device->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    device->IASetIndexBuffer(iBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    std::vector<LINE>::size_type allLines = permanentLines.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < allLines; i++)
    {
        pColour->SetFloatVector(permanentLines[i].colour); // in the line loop too?

        // combine the matrices and render
        D3DXMATRIX matFinal = 
        permanentLines[i].scale     * 
        permanentLines[i].rotation  * 
        permanentLines[i].position  * 
        matView * matProjection;

        pTransform->SetMatrix(&matFinal._11); 
        pRotation->SetMatrix(&permanentLines[i].rotation._11);    // set the rotation matrix in the effect

        pPass->Apply(0);

        device->DrawIndexed(2, 0, 0);
    }

    allLines = temporaryLines.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < allLines; i++)
    {
        pColour->SetFloatVector(temporaryLines[i].colour); // in the line loop too?

        // combine the matrices and render
        D3DXMATRIX matFinal = 
        temporaryLines[i].scale * 
        temporaryLines[i].rotation * 
        temporaryLines[i].position * 
        matView * matProjection;

        pTransform->SetMatrix(&matFinal._11); 
        pRotation->SetMatrix(&temporaryLines[i].rotation._11);    // set the rotation matrix in the effect

        pPass->Apply(0);

        device->DrawIndexed(2, 0, 0);
    }

    temporaryLines.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of "instanced" rendering is to make *one* draw call to draw all of the instances. You are making `allLines` number of draw calls. So no, that's not instancing.

Since each instance is completely separate from the other, sharing absolutely no data at all (the matrix is basically just a bulky way to encode the two endpoints of each line), you would gain nothing from instancing. Instead, you should build a vertex buffer that contains all of the lines (and their colors). If lines change, you change the buffer.

This way, you draw all of them at once.

Comment: and how would I do that? also, is there a name for that technique?

Comment: It's called, "Drawing a lot of lines." ;) And you do it by putting your position and color attributes in the buffer. Then you just make a DrawPrimitive call, only with many vertices instead of just two. If the lines change, you have to change the data in the buffer to match.

Comment: what if I just stored one set of data in a buffer representing one line, then drew that line many times with a list of transforms?

Comment: do you mean a DrawIndex() call?

Comment: the lines share the same index and vertex buffer. does that count for anything?

Comment: @AsherEinhorn: Storing one line and drawing it a lot is what you're doing *now*. Just put a bunch of lines in a vertex buffer and call `Draw`.

Comment: I can see why that would be a lot simpler, but I thought storing one thing and drawing it a lot was the basic idea behind instancing? Except that the transforms are sent through to the GPU not applied in the code as they are now.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider instanced rendering to either be a single Draw call of some sort, where the geometry itself is either duplicated in the buffer N times, or the drawing API renders the mesh N times for you with some per-instance vertex buffer data, or multiple Draw calls with no other API calls in between them (i.e. only changing the starting index or vertex and number of primitives, which you would need to do if you wish to draw less than a whole mesh, but in parts).

Any other API to change textures, rendertargets, shader constants, render state, and shaders calls can incur quite a lot of overhead.